# Ban the [cross] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request, ban

I just got done retagging 78 questions with the [cross](/questions/tagged/cross) tag. In probably 75 of those cases it was done by somebody who typed in "cross browser" instead of "cross-browser" or "cross X" instead of "cross-X" (for whatever value of X). Since "cross" by itself is meaningless in a programming context, can it be banned to prevent future instances of this problem?

Comment: Or perhaps a special case in the tag system: if two adjacent tags, X and Y, can be combined into an existing tag, X-Y, do so.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, but you've left one thing answered—what were the other 3 cases? Did they have a legitimate or near-legitimate use for that tag?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you take the time to do this? What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: he was apparently searching for a question or trying to post one or looked up the automated recommendations for similar questions.

Comment: @user: Obviously trying to improve the site. It's a thankless job, but thank goodness some of us care enough to do it.

Comment: @waiwai933: In the other 3 cases, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947818/, I could find no use for the `[cross]` tag and deleted it.

Comment: In that one, looks to me like the OP wanted `[cross-form]`, in which case your replacement of `[form]` with `[forms]` and deletion of `[cross]` is perfect.